# mysqli extension missing-phpMyAdmin Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I'm sure many have seen this error by now. 
*"The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."*

I have tried uninstalling everything and keep having the same issues. I have read numerous articles trying to fix it, and keep getting the same problem!

Here's what I got:

Windows 7 Professional 64

mySQL 5.6

Apache 2.2.22

PHP 5.3.22

I should also mention that I'm trying to install this on a separate partition on my hard disk, the drive is labeled as F:.

Yes, I've checked to see if mysqli is uncommented.

Yes, I've checked the .dll is in the \ext folder.

Yes, I've restarted the services, my computer, and reinstalled everything.

I'm about at wits end trying to make this thing work. 
If I can't get these to work together, any other ideas for creating the web server with mySQL? I'd like to get this fixed as soon as possible.
Please help!

Comment: I ran into this issue a while back, it had to do with the bit version of Apache PHP and MySQL.  I can't remember exactly what it was, but make sure you download the 64bit version of ALL of them ...  If that doesn't work, you might download the 32 bit of them all and try that.

Comment: 'Yes, I've restarted the services, my computer, and reinstalled everything.' --> sometimes required twice on Windows ;)

Comment: In the worst case you can try XAMPP or WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

about that I had that error before and this is how i corrected it

I downloaded PHP 5.0 then installed into my computer

when opened phpMyAdmin it resulted to the php error it somehow clashed with my php.ini file

but when i uninstalled it my wampserver recovered after i restarted the service.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16 operating system
try to run

```
php -m
```

if mysqli is not shown after running this command then install mysqli

For PHP 7.0 version

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqli
```

For PHP 5 version

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```